# Get next item in LinkedHashMap?

Tags: java, dictionary, linkedhashmap

I have the first key/value pair in a LinkedHashMap, which I get from a loop:

```
for (Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    String value = entry.getValue();
    //put key value to use
    break;
}
```

Later on, based on an event, I need the next key/value pair in the linkedHashMap.  What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Later on in the same function or where?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get an iterator and use `hasNext()` and `next()`:

```
...
Iterator<Entry<String, String>> it = map.entrySet().iterator();
if (it.hasNext()) {
    Entry<String, String> first = it.next();
    ...
}
...
if (eventHappened && it.hasNext()) {
    Entry<String, String> second = it.next();
    ...
}
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Its much easier to have the previous value if you need to compare to consecutive values.

```
String pkey = null; 
String pvalue = null; 
for (Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) { 
    String key = entry.getKey(); 
    String value = entry.getValue(); 

    // do something with pkey/key and pvalue/value.

    pkey = key;
    pvalue = value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than for each loop, use an iterator.

```
Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    String key = entry.getKey();
    String value = entry.getValue();
    // do something
    // an event occurred 
    if (it.hasNext()) entry = (Map.Entry)it.next();
}
```